# Spring JPA Query is not recognizing Spatial Types

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, geometry, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to make a native query request through spring JPA Query annotation using Spacial data types. 
The query works perfectly when asked to execute through the console or even in the database. 
But when he is asked to be used through Spring.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? or there is a better way to achieve the same result (leaving all the calculations DB sided)? 
Thank you in advance

This is the query I'm trying to execute. Again, it works through console but fails to execute through spring boot request

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Vehicles v " +
            "JOIN Bikelots l ON l.BikeLotId = v.BikeLotId " +
            "JOIN BikeTypes b ON b.BikeTypeId = l.BikeTypeId " +
            "WHERE b.BikeTypeId = ?1 " +
            "ORDER BY " +
            "Geography::STGeomFromText(v.Point.MakeValid().STAsText(),4326) " +
            ".STDistance(Geography::STGeomFromText(Geometry::Point(?2,?3,4326).MakeValid().STAsText(),4326)) "
            , nativeQuery = true)
```

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'Geography:'.
```

Im using this dialect in `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.sqlserver.SqlServer2008SpatialDialect
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given error was caused because jpa hibernate recognizes the character ":" as a placeholder for an upcoming variable.

By placing the query in a String variable, then adding "\\" before each ":" and assigning the string to the value of @Query, solved the problem. See code for example

```java
String query = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Vehicles v " +
        "JOIN Bikelots l ON l.BikeLotId = v.BikeLotId " +
        "JOIN BikeTypes b ON b.BikeTypeId = l.BikeTypeId " +
        "WHERE b.BikeTypeId = ?1 " +
        "ORDER BY " +
        "Geography\\:\\:STGeomFromText(v.Point.MakeValid().STAsText(),4326) " +
        ".STDistance(Geography\\:\\:STGeomFromText(Geometry\\:\\:Point(?2,?3,4326).MakeValid().STAsText(),4326)) ";
    @Query(value = query, nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: Fellow KdG student with the exact same problem, Seems like the exercise hasn't changed in the past 3 years. I've been looking for this the entire day I could kiss you right now

Comment: Works all fine for me too. Glad to have this solution.

Comment: You are the man! These little annoyances, costing hours of time...